# How to use mysql custom port in c3p0 datasource?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, c3p0

I have a mysql running on 3306 port in my local system. and also there is another mysql is running on 13000. while im trying to connect to 13000 instance still it is connecting to 3306 instance. c3p0 datasource is taking the default port and it is simply ignoring the port. so could some one help on this???

Spring bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:13000/dbname?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pwd" />

        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="55" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="60" />

        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>
```

**Edit:**
Even simple JDBC program is connecting to 3306.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. The reason is i am using `mysql-connector-java.5.1.9.jar`, so there is a bug in that connector. So i changed it to latest version then my issue got resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

c3p0 doesn't parse JDBC urls or make any assumptions at all about what's in them. It just asks your JDBC driver (via DriverManager, or via a directly instantiated driver if you configure [forceUseNamedDriverClass](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#forceUseNamedDriverClass)) to return Connections for the supplied URL. The issue is definitely not that c3p0 is ignoring the nondefault port. c3p0 is ignoring it all. It has no idea and doesn't care.

I'd try to verify that the JDBC URL you think you are configuring is the one that is actually getting through to the pools you are making. If you have multiple MySQL instances on the machine, maybe you have conflicting config somewhere. c3p0 dumps its configuration to your application's logs at INFO level on pool initiation. Look for that, and verify that the URL your c3p0 DataSource is using is the URL you intended to configure.

Otherwise, try to check to see whether a call to `DriverManager.getConnection( myJdbcUrl )` gets you to the DBMS you want. That's basically what is calling. (It's actually calling `DriverManager.getConnection( myJdbcUrl, info )` where `info` is a Properties object. Unless you've set `forceUseNamedDriverClass` to `true`.)

Comment: Even simple JDBC program is connecting to 3306 instance. I think there might be conflict issue. @Stev